# API Gateway Set-Cookie with Lambda Proxy

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set a cookie from Lambda which goes through API Gateway and it just doesn't seem to be sent through.

This is what I've tried sending:

```
{
  body: JSON.stringify({}),
  headers: {
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
     'test': 'test',
     'Set-Cookie': 'name=test',
  }
}
```

All of the other headers are showing up in chrome under response headers, except the cookie.  I've tried adding `Set-Cookie` to the Method Reponse for `200`, but this made no difference.

Any ideas how to get this to work?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good as following sample is working fine to set cookies

setcookies :

```
 {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "testing set-cookie headers",
  "headers": {
    "X-Test-Header": "vaquarkhan experiment",
    "Set-Cookie": "cookie2=vaquarkhan",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  }
}
```

or

```
   Set-Cookie header to integration.response.header.Set-Cookie
```

You can set cookes using console and check into devloper tools

Steps : On Api gateay Method page, choose Integration Response. Under the Header Mappings section of the default 200 HTTP status, choose the pencil icon to edit the “Set-Cookie” header. In the mapping value section, put:

> integration.response.body.Cookie

[image]

Now next step choose Integration Response. Under the Header Mappings section of the default 200 HTTP status, choose the pencil icon to edit the “Set-Cookie” header. In the mapping value section.

[image]

Now debug - Can you use following link and share what can see in devtools for cookies
- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies

Comment: Integration responses can't be configured for Lambda proxy